# How can I add an expandable textview on Apple TV like in the App Store app (the product description textview)

Tags: swift, uitextview, tvos

How can I add a textview or whatever it is in my Apple TV app that is like the app description in the App Store app on the Apple TV.
It will show a few lines of text and it is clickable and if you click on that, a fullscreen layout will appear with all the text and it is scrollable.

Comment: Do you use TVML? Or do you want to create it with UIKit?

Comment: The Apple TV App Store is built using TVML. If you want to use UIKit you will have to use a custom implementation. Perhaps a `UIButon` with a `UITextView` subview would work.

Comment: I created a UIKit app. But maybe TVML is better? I guess not, because the main feature is just show text and some button actions and so on ... Thanks for your answer, Daniel Storm.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any native component currently on UIKit for those type of View. They have to be created manually.

For the fullscreen scrollable text. You could do it with an scrollable UITextView as you said, adding a couple of gradients on the top and the bottom and a UIBlurEffect as background.

You can take a look to this code doing exactly this:
https://github.com/dcordero/TvOSTextViewer/blob/master/TvOSTextViewer/Sources/TvOSTextViewerViewController.swift

The text button cropping the text is a little bit more complex because it requires changing the layout when focused. And if you want to have a similar behaviour than the one in the store it even requires handling the parallax effect for the background.

You can also take a look to this code doing exactly this:
https://github.com/cgoldsby/TvOSMoreButton/blob/master/Source/Public/Views/TvOSMoreButton.swift

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what I asked for, but also a relevant answer.
Adding this to your **viewDidLoad** and your textView will scroll.

```
textView?.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
self.view.addGestureRecognizer((textView?.panGestureRecognizer)!)
textView?.directionalPressGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
self.view.addGestureRecognizer((textView?.directionalPressGestureRecognizer)!)
```